# Better Pickers Implementation using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I was trying to add BetterPickers Library project to my app in android Studio.
Unfortunately the library I downloaded from Github at https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers doesn't provide a gradle.build file or the typical gradle project file structure... so I'm facing several problems while adding it...
Is there someone who used it ? Do I have to convert the project for Android Studio manually ?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#betterpickers not sure if it's the correct library though :-) If not, you probably have to convert it yourself. Can be done through Eclipse: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: Thanks! If a ready-to-use solution is not available I'll try with that.

Comment: That's why I supplied the first link - I'm not sure if this is the correct BetterPickers project, but try it out :-) When a gradle build is missing it seems people are adding them on behalf of the authors...